# Huge difference between xgb.train and XGBRegressor

Tags: python, xgboost

I try to train the same data with xgb.train and XGBRegressor but the results are too different. I guess I miss some point when training with xgb.train. What am I missing?

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

def rmspe(y_true, y_pred):
    return  (np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square((y_true - y_pred) / y_true))))


X=train_try[selected_feature]
y=train_try["target"]
model = XGBRegressor()
model.fit(X, y)
preds = model.predict(X)
R2 = round(r2_score(y_true = y, y_pred = preds),3)
RMSPE = round(rmspe(y_true = y, y_pred = preds),3)

print(f'Performance of the train prediction: R2 score: {R2}, RMSPE: {RMSPE}')
```

----Performance of the train prediction: R2 score: 0.86, RMSPE: 0.276---

```
import xgboost as xgb

# Convert the training into DMatrixes: DM_train
DM = xgb.DMatrix(X,y)

    # Create the parameter dictionary: params

params = {"booster":"gblinear", "objective":"reg:linear"}

# Train the model: xg_reg
xg_reg = xgb.train(params = params, dtrain=DM, num_boost_round=5)

# Predict the labels of the test set: preds
preds_2 = xg_reg.predict(DM)

# Compute and print the RMSE
R2 = round(r2_score(y_true = y, y_pred = preds_2),3)
RMSPE = round(rmspe(y_true = y, y_pred = preds_2),3)

print(f'Performance of the train prediction: R2 score: {R2}, RMSPE: {RMSPE}')
```

----[23:55:15] WARNING: ../src/objective/regression_obj.cu:171: reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror.
Performance of the train prediction: R2 score: -290.093, RMSPE: 23.251---

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow! might be a good idea to post this on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using two different sets of parameters in `xgb.XGBRegressor` and `xgb.train`. If you use the same parameters you will get the same results as expected, see the code below for an example.

```py
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

def rmspe(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)))

# input data
X, y = make_regression(random_state=0)

# scikit-learn API
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=10)
model.fit(X, y)
y_pred = model.predict(X)

R2 = round(r2_score(y_true=y, y_pred=y_pred), 3)
RMSPE = round(rmspe(y_true=y, y_pred=y_pred), 3)

print(f'XGBRegressor performance: R2 score: {R2}, RMSPE: {RMSPE}')
# XGBRegressor performance: R2 score: 0.993, RMSPE: 0.261

# functional API
data = xgb.DMatrix(X, y)
params = {'objective': 'reg:squarederror', 'booster': 'gbtree'}
model = xgb.train(params=params, dtrain=data, num_boost_round=10)
y_pred = model.predict(data)

R2 = round(r2_score(y_true=y, y_pred=y_pred), 3)
RMSPE = round(rmspe(y_true=y, y_pred=y_pred), 3)

print(f'xgb.train performance: R2 score: {R2}, RMSPE: {RMSPE}')
# xgb.train performance: R2 score: 0.993, RMSPE: 0.261
```